# Linearity of Lebesgue integral in the complex case.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

We suppose that we have proved the following theorem in the *real case*:

**Theorem.** Let $f,g\in L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$,($f,g\colon X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$), $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Then:

\begin{align}
(i)\quad&\int_{X}(f+g)\; d\mu=\int_Xf\;d\mu+\int_X g\;d\mu\\
\\
(ii)\quad&\int_X(\lambda f)\;d\mu=\lambda\int_Xf\;d\mu
\end{align}

I must prove it in the complex case. About that let $f\colon X\to \mathbb{C}$ be a measurable complex function, we denote with $f_r:=\Re(f)$, $f_i:=\Im(f)$, we note that $f_r, f_i$ are real valued function. We said that $f\in L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$(with abuse of notation we indicate with $L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ also the space of integrable functions with complex values) if $f_r,f_i\in L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and define $$\boxed{\int_X f\;d\mu:=\int_Xf_r\;d\mu+i\int_Xf_i\;d\mu}\tag1$$

*Proof* $(i)$ We have
\begin{align}
\int_X (f+g)\;d\mu&:=\int_X (f+g)_r\;d\mu+i\int_X (f+g)_i\;d\mu\\
&= \int_X (f_r+g_r)\;d\mu +i\int_X (f_i+g_i)\;d\mu\\
&=\int_X f_r\;d\mu+\int_X g_r\;d\mu+i\int_X f_i\;d\mu+i\int_X g_i\; d\mu\\
&= \int_X f\;d\mu+\int_X g\;d\mu
\end{align}
We go to prove $(ii)$. We prove the result in the case $\lambda=i$.

\begin{align}
\int_X (if)\;d\mu= \int_X(if_r-f_i)\; d\mu=& \int_X (-f_i)\;d\mu+i\int_X f_r\;d\mu=-\int_X f_i\;d\mu+i\int_X f_r\;d\mu= i\int_X f\; d\mu\tag2
\end{align}

Now we suppose that $\lambda=\lambda_1+i\lambda_2$, where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$, results

\begin{align}
\int_X (\lambda f)\;d\mu =\int_X(\lambda_1 f+i\lambda_2 f)\; d\mu=&\int_X (\lambda_1 f)\;d\mu+\int_X (i\lambda_2 f)\;d\mu\\
\color{blue}{=}&\int_X (\lambda_1 f)\;d\mu +i\int_X (\lambda_2f)\; d\mu\\
\color{red}{=}&\lambda_1\int_X f\;d\mu+i\lambda_2\int_X f\;d\mu\\
=&\lambda\int_X f\;d\mu
\end{align}

For the blue equality I use $(2)$.

For the equality in red I reasoned as follows.

\begin{align}
\color{red}{\int_X(\lambda_1f)\;d\mu=\int_X(\lambda_1 f)_r\;d\mu+i\int_X(\lambda_1 f)_i\;d\mu
=\int_X \lambda_1 f_r\;d\mu+i\int_X\lambda_1 f_i\;d\mu
=\lambda_1\int_X f_r\;d\mu+i\lambda_1\int_X f_i\;d\mu
=\lambda_1\int_X f\;d\mu}
\end{align}

We proceed in the same way for $\int_X (\lambda_2 f)\;d\mu$

Is this way of proceeding correct? Thanks!

Comment: The theorem is obviously true. No reason to assume that your way of proceeding could be incorrect.